# Windows batch file directory as variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I am trying to set a variable to define a directory path. For some reason when I reference it, the batch file acts as if nothing is there.

my batch file is as follows...

```
set project_res_folder =../../Development/androidprojects/myapp/app/src/main/res
echo %project_res_folder%
magick %1 -resize 75%% %project_res_folder%/drawable-xxhdpi/%1
magick %1 -resize 50%% %project_res_folder%/drawable-xhdpi/%1
magick %1 -resize 37%% %project_res_folder%/drawable-hdpi/%1
magick %1 -resize 25%% %project_res_folder%/drawable-mdpi/%1
```

When I run that batch file with a valid argument, the echo simply writes

```
ECHO is on.
```

and all the paths write out as if the project_res_folder var was not even there

```
unable to open image '/drawable-xxhdpi/metal_seekbar_thumb.png'
```

Comment: no space between `project_res_folder` and the equals sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space before the = sign. That should fix it.

```
set project_res_folder=...
```